# Python iterates over an item returned by the generator

Tags: python, list

I try to understand how generators work.

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 31 2019, 18:44:59) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>>> def gen():
...     yield '123'
... 
>>> list(gen())
['123']
>>> list(next(gen()))
['1', '2', '3']
```

Please, explain why python iterates over an item in case of using next()?

Comment: Edit:
Just to be clear, I'm interested in the reason why python iterates over an item in the second case. In the first case, it simply adds an item in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case that's because your generator yields `'123'` with type of `str` - and `next(gen())` is the same value. That's the way `list(str)` works

You can try this code:

```
test = '123' # str
print(list(test)) # will also print ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: good answer, I'd just like to emphasis so it's clear to OP - this behavior has nothing to do with the fact that `gen()` is a generator. It's just how `list(str)` works.

Comment: In the first case generator returns str too, isn't it? But Python simply adds this item in the list without iterating.

Comment: @AndreiPuzanau The difference is, in the first case you iterate over the entire generator (which just so happens to yield just a single element), and in the second case you iterate over that element itself.

Comment: @AndreiPuzanau the first example is remotely equivalent to `list(['123'])` which is `['123']`

Comment: Ah, so there is the misunderstanding. `gen()` returns the generator object, not `str`. Try `type(gen())` It's `<class 'generator'>`.

Comment: `list(<generator object>)` is a list of all values that generator *yields*, and `list(next(<generator object>))` is equivalent to `list(str)` in your case, that's the difference

Comment: Thanks to everyone, now it is clear what is happening